# Appcelerator iOS module crashes with 3rd party framework

Tags: ios, xcode, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am building an Appcelerator module, that requires 3rd party frameworks to be included. I read the documentation and tried to follow it perfectly with little success.

The app id is com.example.app
The version is 1.0

The frameworks are located in iphone/platform.
The module.xconfig is as follows:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=$(SRCROOT)/../../modules/iphone/com.example.app/1.0/platform /Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.example.app/1.0/platform ~/Library/Application\ Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/com.example.app/1.0/platform

OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework NBiometricClient -framework NBiometrics -framework NCluster -framework NCore -framework NDevices -framework NLicensing -framework NMedia -framework NMediaProc
```

All of my classes are included in my target. the module builds without warning or error in XCode. I can publish it without error in Appcelerator. When i launch a simple test application, to see if the module will load, it builds successfully, and then crashes immediately. Appcelerator refrences a crash log, which reads as follows:

```
Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_SHARED_REGION=avoid

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/NBiometricClient.framework/NBiometricClient
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95DD514F-E8D1-4982-B845-6CAC27369DC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/355A1ABF-7036-4285-90B5-96C8F88DAD36/testHarness.app/testHarness
Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
   0x10bb29000 -        0x10c1fffff +com.testHarness (1.1 - 1.1) <4F498C98-61BA-3ED7-99B5-F2F9649FD94A> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95DD514F-E8D1-4982-B845-6CAC27369DC8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/355A1ABF-7036-4285-90B5-96C8F88DAD36/testHarness.app/testHarness
   0x10c571000 -        0x10c59825f +dyld_sim (360.19) <0BF161D7-EFA9-3CBE-AE2B-84F9A70FC853> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/dyld_sim
0x7fff624c8000 -     0x7fff624ff007  dyld (360.19) <9D05FDF4-65CE-3B53-86D4-ABE1A5BF35F3> /usr/lib/dyld
```

The frameworks were added to XCode directly from the platform folder of the module.

Please let me know what else to check or let me know what I should share to get this resolved.

Comment: It has been 8 days now and I still cant get external frameworks to work in Appcelerator. I always get the error "Path not found: $(SRCROOT)/../../modules/iphone/disi.corretrak.facrec/1.0/platform" Is this path correct? Do I need to do anything to create that path myself?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to place the framework in `<your_module>/platform` and referenced it from their inside your Xcode project? Check [ti.googlemaps](https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.googlemaps) where I'm doing the same with the GoogleMaps.framework.

Comment: I notice two things with your project. First, your folder structure is different than what is installed by default from Appcelerator. I have <appname>/iphone/platform. You have <appname>/ios/platform/ios. Second, your googlemaps.framework is actually called googlemaps.bundle. Why is the path and name different?

Comment: Also, I see in the crash report:  "[TRACE]  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/DISI/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/testHarness/build/iphone/../../modules/iphone/disi.corretrak.facrec/1.0/platform'" what does the ../../ part mean and why is this path not found? Isnt that path built automatically?