# Appcelerator module events stop firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a native iOS module that needs to fire events periodically. These events work perfectly... sometimes. Randomly, they just dont fire.

In Obj-C, The button fires an event on the NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter, with a TiBlob image. My module class listens for this notification, and calls the following function:

```
- (void) imageCaptured:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"[INFO] module notified of image capture event");
    if ([self _hasListeners:IMAGECAPTUREDEVENT])
        [self fireEvent:IMAGECAPTUREDEVENT withObject:notification.userInfo];
    else
        NSLog(@"[INFO] if an image is captured, and there is no one there to listen for it, does an event get fired?");
}
```

And then in JS I have an eventlistener like so:

```
mymodule.addEventListener('imageCaptured', function(e){
    Ti.API.info('image capture event caught in JS.);
});
```

This does work some of the time. I can even see the Ti.blob object returned if I add that into the listener, but other times... I see the "[INFO] module notified of image capture event" log, and then nothing. No errors. No clever line about there being no listeners. And no "image capture event caught in JS."

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3521

Comment: In the meantime, I have moved my events to the view itself, using [[self proxy] fireEvent... This seems to work everytime.

Comment: Good to hear you've found a workaround. Could you add that as a comment to your ticket?

Comment: I added the comment. Thanks for the help..

Comment: I actually have a second stackoverflow ticket open, for another issue I am having, and no one seems to be able to offer any help. Can you please take a look and let me know? It is a major obstacle in my ability to develop with the software. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509647/appcelerator-ios-module-crashes-with-3rd-party-framework/36545572#36545572